# Laravel Query get similar book by title

Tags: php, laravel

we have a books table, and When I click on Harry Potter Part 1, it will show me the other parts below, such as Harry Potter Part 2 or Part 3, I try `like query` or `group by`

I tried these but to no result

```
 public function book(Request $request)
    {
        $book = books::find($request->id);
            return [
                'book' => $book,
                'more_books' => books::
                    ->whereNotIn('id', [$book->id])
                    ->where('title', 'like', '%' . $book->title. '%')
                    ->get()
            ];
    }
```

output :

```
{
    "book": {
        "id": 40,
        "price": 20,
        "title": "Harry Potter Part 1"
    },
    "more_books": []
}
```

Comment: If you click `Harry Potter Part 1` then only books that match `'%Harry Potter Part 1%'` will be returned.

Comment: `like` is a substring match, so if you do `like "%Harry Potter Part 1%"` then matches will have to contain that complete string somewhere within the title. You'll probably want to do a [fuzzy search](https://www.google.com/search?q=laravel+fuzzy+search) instead.

Comment: Change `whereNotIn` with `whereNot`, it's work a little bit faster. Are you sure you have another books with similar title? Looks like code is working, but these no results. Maybe you need to use a fulltext search instead?

Comment: The query is doing `where title like '%Harry Potter Part 1%`. What you are looking for, it seems, is `where title like '%Harry Potter Part%'`. So, you might have to do `where('title', 'like', '%' . substr($book->title, 0, strlen($book->title) - 2) . '%')` or something on those lines. If you do this, it'll solve Harry Potter issue but may cause unintended consequences that you should keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

if this is mysql you would use the [MATCH()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html) function to return a relevance, and play around with the results you get from this (and add fullext index to the table). I think in laravel you'll need to add a whereraw in the query builder. Look up the Match function. Other dbs will have the same or similar.

Comment: Since Laravel 9, we can use "whereFullText" to use MATCH() AGAINST() https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#full-text-where-clauses

Answer (score 0):

````
 public function book(Request $request)
    {
        $book = books::find($request->id);
        $title = substr($book->title, 0, -3);

            return [
                'book' => $book,
                'more_books' => books::
                    ->whereNotIn('id', [$book->id])
                    ->where('title', 'like', '%' . $title. '%')
                    ->get()
            ];
    }
    ```
````